# Ctrl key not working in Bootcamp with Win 8.1 Professional

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, boot-camp

I have Windows 8 Pro Student installed via Bootcamp on OS X 10.10 Yosemite.

For some reason, the Ctrl key isn't working as it should within windows. Commands such as Ctrl+F, Ctrl+O, Ctrl+P etc etc etc all do not work because the OS isn't recognising the Ctrl key as it's standard key.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenerio, the <kbd>Command</kbd> key functions as Ctrl.

Comment: This doesn't apply to Bootcamp because in Bootcamp, the cmd key operates as the windows key - so the cmd key always opens the start screen, or can be used for shortcuts such as locking the computer or other windows key based shortcuts. My problem isn't with that functionality, but with the shortcuts coming directly from the Ctrl key.

Comment: Not for me, or [this guy](http://dustyreagan.com/map-the-apple-key-to-ctrl-in-boot-camp/).

Comment: it's strange because I always had no problem prior to now on this fresh install. Cmd+C for example in 8.1 opens the charm menu, not the copy function.

Comment: it is something about the macbook keyboard as an external works just fine!